# Cakephp: find() Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Interestslogs.interest_id' in 'field list'

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called 'Interestslogs' and model's name is Interestlog.

I need to get the client_id according to id from that table in Cakephp.

```
$client_id = $this->Interestslog->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array('Interestslogs.id' => $id),
        'fields' => array('Interestslogs.client_id'),
        )
    );
```

However I am getting database error:

```
Database Error
```

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Interestslogs.interest_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Interestslogs`.`interest_id` FROM `efa`.`interestslogs` AS `Interestslog` LEFT JOIN `efa`.`interests` AS `Interest` ON (`Interestslog`.`interest_id` = `Interest`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `efa`.`clients` AS `Client` ON (`Interestslog`.`client_id` = `Client`.`id`) WHERE `Interestslogs`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1

Comment: **Check that your `Interestslog` table contains the field `interest_id`**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the plural "s" form Interestslogs

```
$client_id = $this->Interestslog->find('first',array(
    'conditions' => array('Interestslog.id' => $id),
    'fields' => array('Interestslog.client_id'),
    )
);
```

and also check your model. If every thing (Client and Interestslog) is associated properly you shouldn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: *(if your relations are all right)*

```
$this->Interestslog->recursive = -1;
$client_id = $this->Interestslog->find('first',array(
     'conditions' => array('Interestslogs.id' => $id),
     'fields' => array('Interestslogs.client_id'),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is interest_id column in your Interestlogs table.

Or try

```
$variable_temp = $this->Interestslog->findById($id);
//debug($variable_temp);
$client_id = $variable['client_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$client_id = $this->Interestslog->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array('Interestslog.id' => $id),
        'fields' => array('Interestslog.client_id'),
        )
    );
```

You should write the table names in the condition/field array without the last "s" since it's added by cakephp automatically.